# Multiple SCSS compiling with Gulp

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, gulp

I'm trying to adapt a configuration Gulpfile to compile SCSS files by generating multiple bundled files relating to their directories. What I've as entry is something like:

```
scss/
   folder-1/
       file1.scss
       file2.scss
       ...
   folder-2/
       file1.scss
       file2.scss
       ...
   ...
```

And what I'm expecting to have as output is:

```
css/
   folder1.bundle.css // Containing only all files inside folder 1
   folder2.bundle.css // Containing only all files inside folder 2
```

Do I need to run multiple times the Gulp-Sass task with different configurations or there is a better way to do that?

I already tested doing something like:

```
gulp.task('sass', () => {
    let tasks = sassConfig.map(config => {
        return gulp.src(config.sass.src)
            .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(rename(config.buildLocations.filename))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildLocations.css))
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
    });

    return merge(tasks);
});
```

And having my configuration array as this:

```
const sassConfig = [
    global: {
        // Global styles configuration
        sass: {
            src: ['./scss/style.scss']
        },
        buildLocations: {
            css: './css/',
            filename: 'commons.bundle.css'
        }
    },
    pdp: {
        sass: {
            src: ['./scss/pdp/_pdp.scss']
        },
        buildLocations: {
            css: './css/pdp/',
            filename: 'pdp.bundle.css'
        }
    },
    plp: {
        sass: {
            src: ['./scss/plp/_plp.scss']
        },
        buildLocations: {
            css: './css/plp/',
            filename: 'plp.bundle.css'
        }
    },
    blog: {
        sass: {
            src: ['./scss/blog/_blog.scss']
        },
        buildLocations: {
            css: './css/blog/',
            filename: 'blog.bundle.css'
        }
    }
];
```

When I run the task only got the first file compiled (commons.bundle.css) but not the rest... Something wrong on the code above?

Also if I try to change the order of the sassConfig array items it still keeps compiling the commons.bundle.css so I guess It's not compiling the first element of the array necessarely...

=====================================

SOLUTION: I've found the error, is caused by the underscores at the begining of each file. That's why also the 'styles.scss' was the only file compiling. After removing all underscores from the filenames they've been compiled!

Comment: You can pass parameters to your task so you can obtain the 2 css files  using parameters [https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/pass-arguments-from-cli.md](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/pass-arguments-from-cli.md)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how can I benefit me of this feature to achieve what I want to do or provide a small code example? Because that doesn't seems to be the solution of my problem since I want to run a single task which compiles the different bundle files from specific scss files

Comment: With my suggest you have to run twice the same task with different config.

Comment: @Sfili_81 I edited my question with updated information about the workaround I'm using, can you tell me if you see something wrong on the code?

Comment: I finally found the error!! Was caused by the underscores at the begining of each file. That's why the 'styles.scss' was the only file compiling. After removing the '_' on all the rest scss they've been compiled.

Comment: @MarcHernández You should post an answer to your question instead of editing the question's corpus. It will be easier to read for people having the same problem as you.